# Link that opens gmail with recipient written

Tags: html

As the title suggests i want to have a link that when pressed gets you to the gmail website and also writes the recipients on the email composer.
I have noticed this link in other questions:

```
<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=someone@gmail.com" target="_blank">Title</a>
```

but i want gmail to open on this link https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new

Answer (score 2):

Is better not to link directly to Gmail, is not safe, and you can't control what they're doing.

If what you want is to link to have an email recipient prefilled, use a [mailto](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-mailto-links/) link. Like:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com" >Contact someone</a>
```

And it will link to the compose screen with email prefilled, using the default mail client, that your visitor has.